# Excel template adjusting based on screen size

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a pre-printed official receipts which has some blank values that will be filled in the re-printing on excel. I already adjusted the excel template which will filled the amount and values on the pre-printed official receipt and works perfectly on my main pc. However, as I print on my other devices (laptop, pc) with different screen sizes. It produces different output on printing which resulted to misalignment of amount and values.

I already tried adjusting widths in rows and columns but the problem persist. How can I prevent the excel template making adjustments based on devices?

Comment: Is the print area defined?

Comment: What do you mean area defined? I just create a template by adjusting width of column and row.

Comment: Look into `Worksheet.PrintArea`. Screen size shouldn't affect what gets printed. More likely, other machines have different print settings and your code is using defaults - hard to tell without the code though.